# Passing dynamically template reference name in a form

Tags: angular

I have a form that I generate by calling a REST API. From begginning i don't have information on how many input i'll build, their type or if they're required or not.
I'm using template driven approach to build the form.

For this I created my html template :

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
     <span *ngIf="category.indexes.length != 0; else noInput">
        <div *ngFor="let indexItem of category.indexes" >
           <div [ngSwitch]="indexItem.dataType">
               <div class="form-group" *ngSwitchCase="'nvarchar'">
                  <label for="{{ indexItem.indexName }}"> {{ indexItem.indexName}}</label>
                  <input
                       class="form-control"
                       type="text"
                       ngModel
                       name="{{ indexItem.indexName }}"
                       id="{{ indexItem.indexName }}"
                       [required]="onRequiredCheck(indexItem)"
                    />
               </div>
               // others swithcase   
           </div>
           <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!templateRefName.valid && templateRefName.touched">
              Please enter a valid {{ indexItem.indexName }}
           </span>
       </div>
       <div>
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
       </div>
    </span>
  </form>
  <ng-template #noInput>
    <h3>No input to fill</h3>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

My issue is that I want to check if the input are correctly filled. For each input i'd like to set a template reference that takes the value of : indexItem.indexName

Comment: imho your approach of using a template driven form is wrong for this kind of dynamic forms. that is what the reactive forms exist for ...

Comment: I'm going to try this... i'll post the answer if i found out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @tommueller I finally solved my issue :
I created a method to get my indexes which calls my API which also allow me to build my form :

```
private getIndexes(categoryId): void {
  this.signupForm = new FormGroup({});

  // let control;
  // extracting the list of indexes from the API response
  const response = this.apiService.getCategoryIndexes(categoryId).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.category = data as CategoriesModel;
      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
      for (let i = 0; i < this.category[0]['indexes'].length; i++) {
        this.indexes.push(this.category[0]['indexes'][i]);
      }
      // tslint:disable-next-line:forin
      this.indexes.forEach((index) => {
          if (index.required === 'YES') {
            this.control = new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]);
          } else {
            this.control = new FormControl(null);
          }
          this.signupForm.addControl(index.indexName, this.control);
      });
    }
  );
```

THis method is also called on ngOnInit & ngOnChange (the form is generated by using a select input.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('# ngOnInit() called');
  console.log('Categories : ' + this.category);
  this.signupForm = new FormGroup({});
  this.getIndexes(this.category?.id);
}
```

Finally I rewrote my HTML to use reactive forms :

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <span *ngIf="indexes.length != 0; else noInput">
        <div *ngFor="let indexItem of indexes" >
           <div [ngSwitch]="indexItem.dataType">
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'nvarchar'" class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ indexItem.indexName }}"> {{ indexItem.indexName}}</label>
                <input
                    #[{{indexItem.indexName}}]
                    class="form-control"
                    id="{{ indexItem.indexName }}"
                    [formControlName]="indexItem.indexName"
                    type="text"
                />
              </div>
              <span *ngIf="!signupForm.get(indexItem.indexName).valid && signupForm.get(indexItem.indexName).touched" class="help-block">
                  <span *ngIf="signupForm.get(indexItem.indexName).errors['required']">
                      Field is required
                  </span>
             </span>
         </div>
      //...
     </div>
  </span>
  <div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
   </div>
</form>
<ng-template #noInput>
  <h3>No input to fill</h3>
</ng-template>
```

Variables must be declared an also initialized (for example) :

```
indexes: IndexesModel[] = new Array<IndexesModel>();
signupForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
control: FormControl = new FormControl();
```